# Troubleshooting `serialize`/`unserialize` issue

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:**

Adding the:

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
```

on top of these tests fixed the issue and tests pass each and every time.

<s>My major suspect is the `symfony/phpunit-bridge` which was actually updated when I moved from `master` to `dev`. I invoke all of my tests  via `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` scripts</s>.

^^^ I jumped to conclusion too early

**The issue:**

I am debugging a weird behavior of `PHPPdf` library that involves serialization to cache and then deserialization on the next run.

The payload being deserialized is:

```
a:5:{s:8:"boundary";r:122;s:10:"attributes";a:4:{s:5:"width";s:3:"595";s:6:"height";s:3:"842";s:13:"margin-bottom";i:0;s:10:"margin-top";i:0;}s:19:"complexAttributeBag";a:0:{}s:15:"formattersNames";a:0:{}s:8:"priority";i:0;}
```

The error I get is:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice: "unserialize(): Error at offset 26 of 224 bytes" at vendor/littlerocket/php-pdf/lib/PHPPdf/Core/Node/Node.php line 1703 {"exception":"[object] (PHPUnit\\Framework\\Error\\Notice(code: 8): unserialize(): Error at offset 26 of 224 bytes at vendor/littlerocket/php-pdf/lib/PHPPdf/Core/Node/Node.php:1703)"}
```

This puts me roughly at `r:122` and `s:10:"attributes"`. The `r` as far as I know, means `reference`.

The data serialized looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how to further debug this issue?

The very tricky part is that this piece of code works flawlessly in my `master` branch, but fails consistently on the `dev` branch. Those branches differ in a way that `master` has the `Symfony 4.4` project and `dev` has the `Symfony 5.4` version (I am in the middle of upgrading)

```
    public function serialize()
    {
        $data = $this->getDataForSerialize();

        $foo = serialize($data);

        $fooDeserialozed = unserialize($foo);

        return serialize($data);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        static::initializeTypeIfNecessary();

        $data = unserialize($serialized);

        $this->setDataFromUnserialize($data); <--- the original error happens here, `false` is being passed to `array` argument...
    }

    protected function setDataFromUnserialize(array $data)
    {
       //   
    }
```

Comment: How is PHPUnit be involved? Are you running tests?

Comment: The problem is the `r:122` which should be `i:122`. https://3v4l.org/C5R8p

Comment: @MarkusZeller Exactly, those are Symfony functional tests

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no "r" in the serialize [format](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/classes_objects/serialization.html). References are [resolved](https://3v4l.org/sTjpa).

Comment: I had trouble finding about it as well, but there is the paragraph in the link you posted: “As you can see it works the same way as with references, just using the small r instead of R.”

Comment: I would say it references to something which is not included in the serialisation. So the decode will fail, because the reference is lost.

Comment: yes, that makes perfect sense, however, in order to prove that I decided to modify class’s serialize function so that it calls serialize then immediately unserialize. The call failed the same way nonetheless… 

Comment: Is it possible, that when the class provides a custom serialize, that it also has a custom deserialize?

Comment: Oh yeah, it does, but it is rather simple. I have updated the question with those functions (modified with my debugging efforts, but without effect)

Comment: Will you please add the code of your test to see a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I am in the process of isolating the minimal reproducible example, however, the more I am trying the more I fail to reproduce it outside of `test` env. It works from browser, it works from sample script, however, it fails from PHPUnit run :(

Comment: What version of PHPUnit is running? Maybe an update will help, if it is only test specific.

Comment: I attempted to `unserialize` the payload from an independent PHP script - it works beautifully, clearly showing unserialized instance `#122` for class `Boundary` (the `r:122` that I suspected caused an error)

Comment: Both `master` and `dev` branches use `PHPUnit 9.5.28` :-/

Comment: ALRIGHTY THEN! I added the `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` on top of my tests and now they pass every time. _head scratching_

Comment: It may be possible, that the state of test suite is altered due to one of the tests.